# In spring mvc 3, how to write a cookie while returning a ModelAndView?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, cookies

My controller method is returning a `ModelAndView`, but there is also a requirement to write a cookie back to client. Is it possible to do it in Spring? Thanks.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you add the response as parameter to your handler method (see [flexible signatures of `@RequestMapping` annotated methods](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-arguments) – same section for [3.2.x](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments), [4.0.x](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments), [4.1.x](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments), [4.3.x](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments), [5.x.x](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-methods)), you may [add the cookie](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addCookie%28javax.servlet.http.Cookie%29) to the response directly:

Kotlin

```
@RequestMapping(["/example"])
fun exampleHandler(response: HttpServletResponse): ModelAndView {
   response.addCookie(Cookie("COOKIENAME", "The cookie's value"))
   return ModelAndView("viewname")
}
```

Java

```
@RequestMapping("/example")
private ModelAndView exampleHandler(HttpServletResponse response) {

        response.addCookie(new Cookie("COOKIENAME", "The cookie's value"));

        return new ModelAndView("viewname");
}
```

Comment: Sometimes you need  to call  ` cookie.setPath("xxx");` if you want to share the cookie between requests.

Answer (score 10):

Not as part of the `ModelAndView`, no, but you can [add the cookie directly](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#addCookie(javax.servlet.http.Cookie)) to the `HttpServletResponse` object that's passed in to your controller method.

Answer (score 8):

You can write a `HandlerInterceptor` that will take all Cookie instances from your model and generate the appropriate cookie headers. This way you can keep your controllers clean and free from `HttpServletResponse`.

```
@Component
public class ModelCookieInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        if (modelAndView != null) {
            for (Object value : modelAndView.getModel().values()) {
                if (value instanceof Cookie)
                    res.addCookie((Cookie) value);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

NB . Don't forget to register the interceptor either with `<mvc:interceptors>` (XML config) or `WebMvcConfigurer.addInterceptors()` (Java config).

Comment: This is especially useful if you want to configure whether to return the data as a Cookie, Header, JSON, etc. and provides good separation of concerns.

Comment: This doesn't seems to work, We probably need a ControllerAdvice https://www.programmersought.com/article/57186340561/

Answer (score -1):

RustyX's solution in Java 8:

```
@Component
    public class ModelCookieInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

        @Override
        public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception{
            if (modelAndView != null) {
                modelAndView.getModel().values().stream()
                    .filter(c -> c instanceof Cookie)
                    .map(c -> (Cookie) c)
                    .forEach(res::addCookie);
            }
        }
    }
```