# Using Cookies to save the values in Spring MVC form fields

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, cookies

Lets say I have a **Spring MVC** form like this:

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/secure/main.htm" commandName="secure/main">

    <form:input path="operatorId" cssClass="textField"/>

    <form:input path="clientId" cssClass="textField"/>

</form:form>
```

What I am trying to do is to store those fields values in the cookies that they will be saved other time user logins into the system. It is similar to `Remember Me` checkbox, but just without the checkbox. My controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processAuthenticate(@Valid AuthenticationForm authenticationForm,
                                  Map<String, Object> model,
                                  HttpServletRequest request,
                                  HttpServletResponse response) {

    authenticationForm = (AuthenticationForm) model.get("authenticationForm");

    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        System.out.println(cookie.getValue());
        if (cookie.getName().equals("clientId")) {
            authenticationForm.setClientId(cookie.getValue());
        } else if (cookie.getName().equals("operatorId")) {
            authenticationForm.setOperatorId(cookie.getValue());
        }
    }

    String clientId = authenticationForm.getClientId();
    String operatorId = authenticationForm.getOperatorId();

    Cookie cookieClientId= new Cookie("clientId", clientId);
    cookieClientId.setMaxAge(COOKIE_EXPIRY);
    response.addCookie(cookieClientId);

    Cookie cookieOperatorId = new Cookie("operatorId", operatorId);
    cookieOperatorId.setMaxAge(COOKIE_EXPIRY);
    response.addCookie(cookieOperatorId);

    return MAIN_FORM_MAPPING;
}
```

But when I click the button and this method is invoked, my values are not saved. It is the first time I am trying to use `Cookies` so maybe I am missing something? I was following [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785254/remember-me-in-jsp-login-page) question. But in my case this does not work. Anybody could advice me with the solution to this problem?

Comment: There are security implications to the way you are storing that data in cookies - is it secure, can someone edit their cookie and see someone else's data, etc? Another way to do this is to store a (hashed ?) key in the cookie and then use that key to retrieve that data from your database.

Comment: Good advice, thanks, I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the false alarm. I was doing everything right, but I had a method which within each request returned new `AuthenticationForm` object as a model attribute, like this:

```
@ModelAttribute("secure/" + MAIN_FORM_MAPPING)
public AuthenticationForm getAuthenticationForm() {
    return new AuthenticationForm();
}
```

And I had a method which is used to show the form in the view:

```
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public String showForm(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request) {
    AuthenticationForm authenticationForm = (AuthenticationForm) model.get("secure/main");
    Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        System.out.println(cookie.getValue());
        if (cookie.getName().equals("clientId")) {
           authenticationForm.setClientId(cookie.getValue());   //Just added this code to this method
        } else if (cookie.getName().equals("operatorId")) {
           authenticationForm.setOperatorId(cookie.getValue());
        }
    }
    return MAIN_FORM_MAPPING;
}
```

Then I realized that this form object is always new, so the values I am setting from cookies always on a new form. I had to set the values from cookies in the `showForm` method and everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether this is useful.
[In spring mvc 3, how to write a cookie while returning a ModelAndView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888456/in-spring-mvc-3-how-to-write-a-cookie-while-returning-a-modelandview)

```
@RequestMapping("/example")
private ModelAndView exampleHandler(HttpServletResponse response) {

        response.addCookie(new Cookie("COOKIENAME", "The cookie's value"));

        return new ModelAndView("viewname");
}
```

Comment: I am adding cookie directly to response, but I am returning the view mapping instead of `ModelAndView`. Does this makes any difference? I don't think so...